# Typescript 1.4: Arrow function without curly braces, syntax changed?

Tags: syntax, typescript, typescript1.4, arrow-functions

I am following some tutorials that says you can do this

```
module testme {
    var testmeA = function(num) => num * num;
}
```

but i am getting an error on the => saying { missing. In the tutorial the above works.

After sometime playing around I got the following to work

```
var testmeA = (num: number) => {return num*num};
```

So you will notice i was "forced" to remove the function keyword, although the tutorial says you can but you are not forced to do and i was forced to add curly brakets after the =>

I was hoping for some insight to understand if I am doing something wrong or the syntax has changed ?

If the syntax has changed, where is the change documented ?

The version I am using is

```
➜  ~  tsc -v
message TS6029: Version 1.4.1.0
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove only the `function` keyword:

```
var testmeA = (num: number) => num * num;
```

Comment: Ah thanks Nikon, so I presume the syntax had changed then ? Before it wasn't mandatory to remove the function?

Comment: @Martin, as far as I can tell, arrow functions have always looked like this. See section 4.9.2 of the [TypeScript language specification](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf) and also the list of [Breaking Changes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes) on the TypeScript wiki.